# DELETE using INNER JOIN sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm trying to delete rows of table "eventos" in sqlite like this:

```
DELETE e FROM `eventos` AS e
INNER JOIN `noticias` AS n ON e.noticiasId=n.id
WHERE n.fechaExpiracion < DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
```

I have the following error

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "e": syntax error
```

I´m not sure why I have this error, I thik that sqlite dont allows to use `AS`

Comment: The SQL Syntax for `DELETE` is `DELETE FROM [table] WHERE [condition]`. You may be able to do something along the lines of `DELETE FROM eventos WHERE noticiasId IN ( SELECT id FROM noticias WHERE... )`

Comment: Neither does SQLite allow joins in DELETE, or DATE_SUB().

Comment: Thanks @323go it worked with:

`DELETE FROM eventos 
WHERE noticiasId IN (
  SELECT id
  FROM noticias
  WHERE fechaExpiracion < DATE('NOW','-1 WEEK'));`